# Can I see finger's user name in htop?

Tags: top, htop, processes, finger

`top`/`htop` show userids. On our shared HPC, these are cryptic. I then need to manually do `finger <username>` to figure out who the user is.

Is there a way of getting `top` or `htop` to include this information right away?
Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you running? I've never seen a `top`  or `htop` implementation that shows UIDs instead of user names.

Comment: I second what terdon says: I have never seen top/htop showing UIDs instead of usernames

Comment: Do you mean that top shows user logins (e.g., `user1278`), but that you would like to see the person's full name instead (e.g., "John Smith")?